# Calculate Full Cartons plus Units (Case plus Each) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, I want to set up a *Stock Picking* sheet.

I have a column for **items per case**, and I have have a **total order quantity** from several different orders to go in a shipment.

So, say I have combined orders of 10,000 and a case quantity of 48.
10,000 divided by 48 gives me 208.333333 in Excel.

How can I express that as 208 Full cases and 16 units?

And the next products down the list could have different "per case" quantities (24, 12, 36, 9 etc.) so I need the formula to suit this variety - not just be set for one case quantity.

I also have a further need, in another location, to break down from a "Cases per Pallet" which is a similar thing. (I have a column for those figures.)

Ultimately in this location I need my 10,000 to be expressed in ***x*** full pallets, plus ***y*** extra full cases, plus ***z*** extra units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

To get the integer division result use [`QUOTIENT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/QUOTIENT-function-9f7bf099-2a18-4282-8fa4-65290cc99dee). For example

```
=QUOTIENT(10000, 48)
```

To get the remainder use [`MOD`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MOD-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). For example

```
=MOD(10000, 48)
```

---

To divide by multiple units you need to get the new divisor after each step. The easiest way is creating separate columns for each different thing, then just hide the columns you don't need

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **total units** | **cases per pallet** | **units per case** | **full pallets** | **units remaining** | **full cases** | **units remaining** |
| 2 | 10000 | 36 | 48 | =QUOTIENT(A2, B2*C2) | =A2-D2*C2*B2 | =QUOTIENT(E2, C2) | =MOD(E2, C2) |
| 3 | 10000 | 36 | 48 | 5 | 1360 | 28 | 16 |

After all you have the needed quantities and now you can combine them into one sentence easily.

```
=D2 & " full pallets, plus " & F2 & " extra full cases, plus " & G2 " extra units."
```

If you can't create hidden columns then the following formula can tell all things in one line, but as you can see now it's very unreadable and inefficient because many things will have to be calculated again and again

```
=QUOTIENT(A2, B2*C2) & " full pallets, plus " &
 QUOTIENT(A2-QUOTIENT(A2, B2*C2)*C2*B2, C2) & " extra full cases, plus " &
 MOD(A2-QUOTIENT(A2, B2*C2)*C2*B2, C2) & " extra units"
```

Comment: Thanks! That is useful for a two-step process, such as Full Cases and Units. But I am finding it hard to make it work for _Full Pallets_ plus _Full extra Cases_, plus _extra Units._

Example: 
I expect 10,000 units to be delivered
The known quantities are   48 units per case, and 
36 cases per pallet. 

I want to be able to check the stock from a list which tells me this answer -  like this:

FULL PALLETS       5
Plus FULL CASES  28
Plus Units                16

( Where Full pallets are 5 @ (36x48)  = 5 @ (1728)  =  8640
Full cases are  28 @ 48    =  1344
Units are    16  )

Comment: @PaulC please see my edit